# The free group of a group and the kernel of a canonical morphism

Tags: gr.group-theory

Let $G$ be a group and $F_G$ the free group on the set $G$. Then there exists a canonical surjective morphism ${\rm can}: F_G \to G \to 1$ constructed as follows: let $(e_x)_{x \in G}$ be a copy as a set of $G$; then $F_G$ is the free group generated by $(e_x)_{x \in G}$ -- then ${\rm can}$ is the unique morphism of groups such that ${\rm can} (e_x) := x$, for all $x\in G$.

Is the set $\{e_x e_y e_{xy}^{-1}\}$ a system of generators of ${\rm Ker} ({\rm can})$?

Comment: .@Gigel Militaru I put a remark in my answer but, now, am not sure of the real statement you are looking for. Can you elaborate a bit ?

Comment: @Duchamp Gérard H. E., The question arise in the context of the classical theory of Schur concerning the covers and universal central extensions for (perfect) groups. I am trying to obtain a similar results for Hopf algebras. Unfortunately, I did not found a detailed proof (the one that can be exposed to students at blackboard :) ) of the original theorem of Schur: probably is buried somewhere in the literature. In this context the theorem reduce to ... the above question. :)

Comment: .@GigelMilitaru I worked in symmetric functions and Hopf algebras some years ago, maybe I can help, what is this theorem by Schur ? (even if the form is incomplete and/or erroneous)

Comment: @Duchamp Gérard H. E - Theorem (Schur): A group G has an universal central extension  (UCS) iff G is a perfect group. An UCS of a group $G$ is a pair $(E, p)$, where $p: E \to G$ is an epimorphism such that ${\rm Ker} (p)$ is contained in the center of $E$ and $(E, p)$ is an intial object in the category of all these pairs (with the obvious morphisms). The above question is the key point of proving Schur theorem at the level of groups: now, we just have to take $E$ the derived group of the quotient of $F_G$ by the normal subgroup generated by all $[e_x e_y e_{xy}^{-1}, \, e_z]$.

Answer (score 5):

The answer is finally yes.

Write $$f(x,y)=e_xe_ye_{xy}^{-1};\qquad R=\{f(x,y):x,y\in G\}\subset F_G.$$ Clearly the presentation $$\langle (e_g)_{g\in G}\mid (f(x,y))_{x,y\in G}\rangle$$
is a presentation of $G$, more precisely if $\Gamma$ is the group defined by this presentation and $\bar{e}_g$ the image of $e_g$ in $\Gamma$, we have a unique homomorphism $\phi:\Gamma\to G$ mapping $\bar{e}_g\mapsto g$ for all $g$. The first claim is that $\phi$ is an isomorphism.

Proof: [added in edit] clearly $\phi$ is surjective. Now in $\Gamma$, the inverse of $\bar{e}_g$ is equal to $\bar{e}_{g^{-1}}$; in particular every element of $\Gamma$ is a product of some of the $\bar{e}_g$ (without inverses). Since in $\Gamma$ we have $\bar{e}_g\bar{e}_h=\bar{e}_{gh}$, this shows that every element of $\Gamma$ is equal to $\bar{e}_g$ for some $g\in G$ and $\bar{e}_1=1$, and it immediately follows that $\mathrm{Ker}(\phi)$ is trivial. Hence $\phi$ is an isomorphism. $\Box$

Thus, the *normal* subgroup generated by $R$ is equal to the kernel $K$ of the canonical homomorphism $F_G\to G$ (mapping $e_g\mapsto g$).

The other (independent) step is to show that the subgroup $L$ of $F_G$ generated by $R$ is normal in $F_G$:

Indeed, we have the formula 
$$e_zf(x,y)e_z^{-1}=f(z,x)f(zx,y)f(z,xy)^{-1},$$
showing that $e_zLe_z^{-1}\subset L$.

Now let $U$ be the set of $w\in F_G$ such that $wLw^{-1}\subset L$. To show that $L$ is normal, we have to show that $U=F_G$. We know that $U$ is a subsemigroup of $F_G$, contains the positive generators, and contains $L$. It remains to show that it contains the inverses of generators. Indeed, we have
$$e_z^{-1}=e_z^{-1}e_{z^{-1}}^{-1}e_{z^{-1}}=f(1,1)^{-1}f(z^{-1},z)^{-1}e_{z^{-1}}\in U.\quad\Box$$

We can now combine both steps: since $L$ is normal (by the second step) and contains $R$, it contains the normal subgroup generated by $R$, which by the first step equals $K=\mathrm{Ker}(\mathrm{can})$. So $L=K$.

Comment: .@YCor I delete my answer in favor of yours, which is more complete. Thank you for the interaction.

Comment: "and this is an isomorphism" -- why?

Comment: .@darijgrinberg I think YCor shoud have written $\tilde{e_g}\mapsto g$ because $\tilde{e_g}$ is taken in the quotient of the free group. Now, we have a (set-theoretical) maps $g\mapsto e_g\mapsto \tilde{e_g}$ and the composite $g\mapsto \tilde{e_g}$ is easily shown to be the reciprocal of the first arrow.

Comment: @DuchampGérardH.E. thanks too. You're right I used $e_g$ both in $F_G$ and in the quotient.

Comment: @YCor - thank you very much for your nice and detalied proof. It is the key point of proving the (I should say trivial :) ) theorem of Schur concerning the existence of the universal central extension of a perfect group. I have included detalis on other comment above.

Answer (score 3):

Decided to add a separate answer for something mentioned in comments: the positive answer follows (almost) immediately from the Nielsen-Schreier theorem. I think it is worth it also because what one gets is a system of **free** generators for $\mathrm{Ker(can)}$: what that theorem actually immediately gives is that $\mathrm{Ker(can)}$ is freely generated by $e_1$, $e_xe_{x^{-1}}$ and $e_xe_ye_{xy}^{-1}$ for $x\in G\setminus\{1\}$, $y\in G\setminus\{x^{-1}\}$. This then obviously implies what we need since $e_1=e_1e_ye_{1y}^{-1}$ and $e_xe_{x^{-1}}=(e_xe_{x^{-1}}e_{xx^{-1}}^{-1})e_1$.

The theorem in full generality states that for a group $F$ freely generated by a set $X$, any subgroup $K$ of $F$ is freely generated by the set
$$
\left\{\tau(Kw)x\tau(Kwx)^{-1}\mid w\in F,x\in X\right\}\setminus\{1\}
$$
where $\tau:K\backslash F\to F$ is any section of the quotient map $F\twoheadrightarrow K\backslash F$ which gives a *Schreier transversal*, i. e. has the property that the image of $\tau$ is closed under taking left prefixes.

To obtain what we want just take $X=G$, $F=F_G$, $K=\mathrm{Ker(can)}$ and let $\tau: G\to F_G$ be given by $\tau(x)=e_x$ for $x\ne1$ and $\tau(1)=1$.

For an elementary proof of the Nielsen-Schreier see e. g. ["An elementary proof that subgroups of free groups are free"](http://arxiv.org/pdf/1006.3833.pdf) by [Benjamin Steinberg](https://mathoverflow.net/users/15934/benjamin-steinberg).

Answer (score 2):

Yes $\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ $

**Later**

After quite some effort several people managed to convince me in the comments that the question is **not** as trivial as my answer seemed to imply. So I felt obliged to acknowledge it.

Still let me try to give an argument which hopefully shows why I was inclined to give that particular answer.

The subgroup $K$ generated by the words $e_xe_ye_{xy}^{-1}$ is clearly in the kernel.

To show it coincides with the kernel it suffices to show that the resulting surjective map $K\backslash F_G\twoheadrightarrow G$ (from left cosets to $G$) is injective.

To show that it suffices to reduce any word from $F_G$ to a single letter using only left multiplications by elements of $K$.

For all $x,y\in G$ the subgroup $K$ contains $e_{xy}\left(e_xe_y\right)^{-1}=\left(e_xe_ye_{xy}^{-1}\right)^{-1}$;

it also contains $e_1=e_1e_1e_{1\cdot1}^{-1}$;

hence it also contains $e_{x^{-1}}e_x=\left(e_{x^{-1}}e_xe_{x^{-1}x}^{-1}\right)e_1$.

Using this, given any word in the $e_x$es, start reading it from the left and do the following:

encountering an $\left(e_x\right)^{-1}$, multiply from the left by $e_{x^{-1}}e_x$ and cancel - as a result, the leftmost $\left(e_x\right)^{-1}$ will become replaced with $e_{x^{-1}}$;

encountering an $\left(e_1\right)^{\pm1}$, multiply from the left by $\left(e_1\right)^{\mp1}$ - as a result, the leftmost $\left(e_1\right)^{\pm1}$ drops out;

encountering $e_xe_y$, multiply from the left by $e_{xy}\left(e_xe_y\right)^{-1}$ - as a result, the leftmost $e_xe_y$ becomes replaced with $e_{xy}$.

Clearly one ends up either with a single $e_x$ or with the empty word which may (if one wishes) be replaced with $e_1$.

Now let me ask - is not all this ridiculously superfluous? :D

**Still slightly later**

Oops it remains to explain what to do with leftmost $e_x\left(e_y\right)^{-1}$ - in that case one has to multiply from the left by $e_{xy^{-1}}e_y\left(e_x\right)^{-1}=e_{xy^{-1}}e_y\left(e_{xy^{-1}\cdot y}\right)^{-1}$.

So I actually have to admit that I cannot make it any simpler than YCor's answer.

Comment: Since the question is trivial and this is the correct answer, I think the downvotes are quite unnecessary.  +1.

Comment: @HJRW Depends on whether users feel the answer was useful. Usually an answer of "yes" with no explanation is not considered useful.

Comment: Exact, moreover the question deserves to be discussed in particular what is understood by "generates". I maintain that the question, correctly discussed, is interesting.

Comment: @ToddTrimble, I think this answer is more useful than the question, which should probably have been closed as 'not research level'.

Comment: @HJRW Well, if that's the case, then the question would have been better left unanswered. Answering a question can be seen as tacit approval of the question as appropriate for this site. We should not be sending mixed messages. (That is to say: if a question is to be answered at all, it should be answered seriously, not flippantly.)

Comment: @HJRW, probably you are right and the question is trivial to the experts in the field. However, I avoid to use the expresion 'trivial' when I am teach math to my students: sometimes the devil hide in the details. I have explained above that the question goes back to the ... history :) - in this case to Schur. All the best and thank you all for your nice answers.

Comment: PS: On the oher hand your opinion is opposite to the one of Ycor :) : ''The question is thus clearly non-trivial and should not be closed''. These facts puzzled me.

Comment: I certainly regret to have induced so much concern with my answer. But I still believe it is trivial. More precisely I believe that the fact that the quotient of $F_G$ obtained by identifying $e_xe_y$ with $e_{xy}$ for all $x$, $y$ is precisely $G$ does not need any further justification.

Comment: .@მამუკაჯიბლაძე ჯიბლაძე Philosophically non-surprising and technically sophisticated !

Comment: @DuchampGérardH.E. Certainly the proof of the much more general fact, the [Nielsen-Schreier theorem](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Nielsen-Schreier+theorem), which instantly implies the answer to this question (I mean that proof which explicitly produces the free generating set), may be called technically sophisticated. But this particular case is in my opinion qualitatively simpler.

Comment: @მამუკაჯიბლაძე I'm sorry, I must be missing a nuance. I agree with your observation two comments ago, but how does that trivialize the argument supplied by YCor (that the group generated by elements $e_x e_y e_{xy}^{-1}$ equals the normal subgroup generated by those elements)?

Comment: @მამუკაჯიბლაძე - please define what the 'trivial' word  means in math :) Yes, a nice theorem proved between 1904-1911 by Schur can be considered trivial in 2015 :) My question, is just the key point of proving the theorem of Schur and I have to thanks again to the all people that participate at the discusion. Now, I am able to show it to  my students :)

Comment: @GigelMilitaru I must admit you are right. After all, analyzing a proof, no matter how straightforward, might give some insights into more general cases

Comment: @მამუკა ჯიბლაძე I agree that in any case "yes" is not a suitable answer and should have been a comment. And if your point is that it is trivial (regardless of the issue about taking the normal subgroup generated or the plain subgroup generated...), even the answer "Yes, it's trivial" would have been more informative about what you want to convey (albeit still more suitable for a comment). Regardless of this specific question, answering just "yes" is, in my opinion, only spam.

Comment: @ToddTrimble Given a word in the $e_x$es, factoring by the subgroup in question means you may start from the left and (1) erase any $e_1$ which occurs; (2) replace any $(e_x)^{-1}$ with $e_{x^{-1}}$; (3) replace any $e_xe_y$ with $e_{xy}$. You end up with a single $e_x$ or with the trivial word.

Comment: @YCor I admit it, it was done partly on impulse partly as a (bad) joke. But the impulse had a good reason behind it.

Comment: And having written down my argument I also admit it is not entirely trivial :D

Comment: (and moreover incomplete - see the second addon in the answer!)

Comment: :) Now, we have three or four different proofs of an trivial question :)

Comment: @GigelMilitaru YES :)

Comment: .@მამუკაჯიბლაძე I like your proof which leads to an explicit algorithm +1